# Tests not being discovered in JUnit 5 ConsoleLauncher, no errors

Tags: java, appium, junit5

I'm trying to run a set of Appium tests that use `JUnit 5` with the `JUnit 5` ConsoleLauncher. I can run the tests successfully within IntelliJ IDEA using the default runner through the GUI.

The ConsoleLauncher does not give any errors when I run it, but it also doesn't actually discover/run any tests.

[image: ConsoleLauncher output]

Here's the command I'm using:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.2.0.jar -cp . -cp C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.11.0\selenium-api-3.11.0.jar -c com.test.package.testsets.TestClass
```

I had to add the path to selenium-api because of this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities

I've been troubleshooting this and playing around with different options for a while now without any luck. I'm guessing it's user error on my part, but I'm not sure what to try next at this point. Anyone know what I might be doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use `--scan-class-path` instead of `-c com.test.package.testsets.TestClass`?

Comment: Also, what are the contents of the directory in which you are executing `java -jar ...`?

Comment: @Sormuras I had to add a new location to the classpath because doing `--scan-class-path` caused a new NoClassDefFoundError. After adding the missing classpath, I am getting the exact same output as before.  
---
@SamBrannen The contents are the junit-platform-console-standalone-1.2.0.jar and then the parent directory of the test class package which contains all the test binaries.

Comment: Are your tests named according to the default class name filter (`Test*` or `*Tests?`)  that ConsoleLauncher uses?

Comment: @MarcPhilipp Thank you so much, that was it. I added Tests to the end of the test classes and it's now running.

Comment: Which is strange. As the default inclusion pattern is: class names that begin with "Test" or end with "Test" or "Tests". And your name starts with "Test". A bug in the regular expression?

Comment: Could in fact be a bug in the regular expression.

Comment: @Taryn, would you mind opening an issue here? https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new?milestone=5.3+M1

Comment: Created https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1463

Comment: @Taryn, `com.test.package.testsets.TestClass` appears to me to be an _example_ name. Can you please tell us the exact _fully qualified class name_ of the test class you were originally trying to execute before you added the `Tests` suffix? (That would help us a lot in debugging this issue)

Comment: I'm asking, because `com.test.package.testsets` is not a valid package name in Java, which makes me think that perhaps your test class was actually name something other than `TestClass` originally.